# How to read from a file to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, filereader

i'm having some trouble with reading from a text file back and writing back to an array list. I was wondering if you could tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
accountArrayList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

private void fileIn()
{
    try
    {
        createTestAccounts();
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(bankFile));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File: " + bankFile + " has been opened for importing");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bankFile.txt"));
        String account = reader.readLine();
        while(account !=null) {
           accountArrayList.add(account); // - add a new account to the text file, but exception show that String cannot be converted to Bank Account
           account = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: Does your file have multiple accounts, one on each line? You are only ever reading the first line of the file, so you'll only get the first account, and then you've got an infinite loop.

Comment: What problem exactly are you encountering?

Comment: You are adding a `String`, but the `list.add` method expects an object of type `BankAccount`. You'll have to find a way to turn that String into an Object of that type , then add the latter. Maybe there is a `fromString()` factory method? Or a Constructor that takes an initialization - String ?

Comment: You should never *ever* catch (Exception)

Comment: Please update the question with what errors are you getting and / or what isn't working as you expect.

Comment: yeah theres multiple objects in the array list, and the problem is that its not writing the lines from the file back to the array

Answer (score 4):

You are adding a `String`, but the `list.add` method expects an **object** of type `BankAccount`.

You'll have to find a way to turn that String into an Object of that type , then add the latter. Maybe there is a fromString() factory method? Or a Constructor that takes an initialization - String ?

If there is a constructor then it should look like

```
accountArrayList.add(new BankAccount(account));
```

Answer (score 1):

To read all lines you may use (if your file is in UTF-8):

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines("bankFile.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But as it was mentioned in the other comments you will need to transform a `String` into a `BankAccount`

Answer (score 0):

```
BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(account);
accountArrayList.add(ba);
```

You're going to need something like this...depending on what your BankAccount class is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The arraylist expects an `BankAccount` object, instead you are reading from a file, so the arraylist should be String.

```
ArrayList<String> accountArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

For the while loop condition, personally, i always use, but you can do it like that too.

```
while((account = reader.readLine()) != null){
    accountArrayList.add(account);
}
```

Comment: While your loop-construct is also right, OP's will work ... so I object that it is "wrong".

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  Better to turn the string into the type he wants than to pollute the domain data with Strings all over the place.

Comment: @Fildor yes you are right, OP's code would work if there was only one line in the file.

Comment: Why do you think so @WonderWorld ?

Comment: The OP's code will work no matter how long the file is because he does a read inside the loop, as well as before it.  There's nothing wrong with that other than using two lines where one might do.

Comment: Ah i see, overlooked the `reader.readLine()` in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `String` constructor for `BankAccount`, something like this:

```
public BankAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
}
```

You can use Apache commons-io and java 8 to get a one-liner!

```
List<BankAccount> accounts = FileUtils.readLines(new File(filename))
    .stream().map(BankAccount::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```